# zooming in on image, showing more details

Tags: iphone, image, ios, ios4, zooming

I am working on a little project and want to implement some sort of "google maps" zooming. What I mean with that is that I want to show an image, and let the user be able to zoom in into a bit of the picture.

The first image should show an overall view of an airport, with its terminals and gates ect. But when zooming in on a terminal it should show more details on where bus stops, taxi stops, info, café's ect are located. It should NOT be a map.

I have searched Google a bit, but couldn't really find anything. Anyone who has any suggestions? Preferable links to tutorials for similar things?

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to implement this is by using a `UIScrollView` and within the `UIScrollView` add a custom `UIView` with `CATiledLayer` layers. You will render the image by drawing (setting content) to the inner `CATiledLayer` layers. Look at the [PhotoScroller sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: If I understand that example correctly it uses two scrollviews and one UIView. The first scrollview is for paging different images (which I don't need), the 2nd is for scrolling the (zoomed) content and the UIViews are the different images themselfs (the tiles). Correct? Do you have any links explaining this example better?

Comment: Right, the class you really care about is ImageScrollView. If the code is not clear I suggest you work your way through the UIScrollView Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/) and the Core Animation programming guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). This are relatively advanced iOS topics. Sorry I don't have a more succinct pointer to offer.

Comment: No problem. I'll read thru it tonight. Really want to get this to work so it's worth it. Also, it adds kind of a "wow-factor" to the app. I'll post when the app is available on iTunes so you can see the result :)

Comment: The link to the result: http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/flyget-arlanda/id411405463?mt=8